# Rules for prone in D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

What are the combat advantages/disadvantages for being prone in D&D 4e?  My group plays it the same as in 3.5.

- +2 Melee attacks vs prone (but not combat advantage)
- -2 Ranged attacks vs prone.

Is this correct?  I can't find it *anywhere* in my PHB. Where can I find this rule?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compendium states the following, which agrees with the Jeremiahs PHB quote and add some detail:

1. You grant combat advantage to enemies making melee attacks against you.
2. You can’t move from your space, although you can teleport, crawl, or be forced to move by a pull, a push, or a slide.
3. You get a +2 bonus to all defenses against ranged attacks from nonadjacent enemies.
4. You are lying down. However, if you are climbing or flying, you fall.
5. You take a -2 penalty to attack rolls.

Number 4 is referring to being knocked prone.

Answer (score 4):

PHB page 277 states:

- Combat advantage to enemies
- +2 to your defense against range from non adjacent
- -2 penalty to attack rolls you make
- Drop prone as minor action

Comment: Just to add: one big difference is that getting up from prone no longer provokes opportunity attacks.  I think that's the biggest change.

Comment: Note that the combat advantage only applies to enemies making melee attacks against you. Also, standing up is a move action, not a minor action.

Comment: Did they errata the PHB section? Darn errata.

Comment: Nah, PHB p. 277 does say that the CA is only for melee attacks.

Comment: @Bryant I meant about dropping prone being a minor action.

Comment: Dropping is minor, standing up is move.

Comment: Wait, thats horribly written. Dropping prone doesn't mean get rid of the prone condition it means gaining the prone condition. Also the Compendium should crossreference to standing up instead of you then having to go look it up.